# Python tarfile fails when installing sqlite3 via nodejs/npm on embedded linux

Tags: python, node.js, sqlite

I'm trying to install an node-based webserver on a cortax a7 embedded system. The repos is pulled via git and I need to run npm install to install the node modules.

The server uses sqlite3, but the package fails when installing, specifically at the build stage, because python cannot find the tarfile module.

```
node -v // 4.3.1
npm -v // 2.14.12

root@imx6ul-var-dart:~/gateway-server# npm install
> sqlite3@3.1.1 install /home/root/gateway-server/node_modules/sqlite3
> node-pre-gyp install --fallback-to-build
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./extract.py", line 2, in <module>
    import tarfile
ImportError: No module named tarfile
deps/action_before_build.target.mk:13: recipe for target 'Release/obj/gen/sqlite-autoconf-3090100/sqlite3.c' failed
make: *** [Release/obj/gen/sqlite-autoconf-3090100/sqlite3.c] Error 1
make: Leaving directory '/home/root/gateway-server/node_modules/sqlite3/build'
```

I'm aware that many users experience issues with gyp/node-gyp, but here it seems its actually the python file extract.py that fails, when trying import tarfile ... but this seems to be a core module.

I've not been able to find references to this in my searches and bluntly I'm not a python guy. Ideas?

Comment: How old is the python version on the server?

Comment: tarfile has been around since 2.3 so unless you have an ancient version of python on the server then it should be there

Comment: `python --version` shows 2.7.9.

however, running python in shell and trying to import tarfile throws the same error.

Comment: So `ls /usr/lib/python2.7` shows .py/.pyc files but there is no tarfile.py. What am I missing? I'm reading that tarfile is part of python-core since 2.3?

Answer (score 0):

For anyone finding this after-the-fact, it seems you have to install python-modules package (in my case, with opkg) to get ALL the python standard libraries .... dunno why ... but this brings over tarfile and subsequent dependent zlib